# Building a react-flow app with third party APIs as nodes

Tags: reactjs, node.js, architecture, react-flow

I had an idea for a personal project in which I would like to use third party APIs to create workflows by using react-flow. It's a bit of a daunting project for me but it is one I wanna do as I know it will involve a lot of learning and practice. Having said that, I was wondering if I could get some insight into this. Normally, I'd build the API first and test that out and then work on the frontend. How should I proceed with this app where I would be integrating third party APIs?

I am just looking for some insight from experienced people who can give me insight as to how one would break this down and approach a project like this. I would appreciate that a lot.

I'm just using React for the frontend and NodeJS for backend.